# Angular5 browser not supported message

Tags: firefox, angular5

I just updated my app to Angular5. As standard business expectation that it should work on mostly browser.

Angular 5 is not working in old browser. I just checked on browserstack it works in newer version of firefox(after 51). What should I do to make it work at least upto version 30. There are many users using older version of firefox.

Is there anyway that we can show them at least error message that the version of firefox is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking my polyfills.ts file and making sure that I have enabled and installed all my polfills for old browsers. Refer to [this](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) page of Angular documentation if enabling the default polyfills doesnt work

```
    /**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
// import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

If setting your polyfills doesn't allow your app to support the Firefox version you're targeting, then I would place a script tag within your index.html that uses window.navigator object to detect the browser. Placing it outisde the Typescript code, should allow your browser detection logic to execute even when Angular fails. After detecting the browser, you can then handle result however you need. Below is the code to get the browser version:

```
<script>
   var browserVersion = navigator.appVersion;

   // Your logic here...
</script>
```

References:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent